# Cordova Universal Links Plugin is not working with IP address

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have installed my Cordova app in my mobile. I have my project domain http://example.com URL in my Gmail. When I click it I'm able to launch my installed Cordova app.

When I have http://91.112.148.70:34536 URL in my Gmail and I click it I'm not able to launch my installed Cordova app. It is opening in Gmail in-app browser.

Please help me how to open the app when we click the IP address from Gmail account

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="domain.com" />
    <host name="91.112.148.70:34536" />
</universal-links>
```